# java build from command line, multiple, pdfbox

Tags: java, cmd, module, jar, pdfbox

hello i have made a java gui that works fine when run with visualstudioc, and now i want to create a run.bat to run it faster so i made the jar file, at first i only had the javaFx modules and it worked fine, but now i added pdfbox and i don't know how to write the bat file.
I tried it like this:

```
java --enable-preview --module-path "javafx\lib" --add-modules javafx.web,javafx.media,javafx.swing,commons-logging-1.2,fontbox-2.0.19,pdfbox-2.0.19,pdfbox-tools-2.0.19 -jar programa.jar
```

all modules are in the same folder.

it returns this error:

```
java.lang.module.FindException: Module pdfbox-2.0.19 not found
```

Before, when I didn't use pdfbox, it worked like this:

```
java --enable-preview --module-path "javafx\lib" --add-modules javafx.web,javafx.media,javafx.swing -jar programa.jar
```

thanks for your help

Comment: is the pdfbox-2.0.19 module installed in the javafx\lib path?

Comment: yes pdfbox-2.0.19 is in javafx\lib path

Answer (score -1):

never mind, it is working i added the pdfbox modules to the jar of my program, now it works just whit this:

```
java --enable-preview --module-path "javafx\lib" --add-modules javafx.web,javafx.media,javafx.swing -jar programa.jar
```

thanks for the help :)

Comment: The current version is 2.0.25 !